# T-SQL query for SQL Server 2008 : how to query X # of rows where X is a value in a query while matching on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

*Summary:*

I have a list of work items that I am attempting to assign to a list of workers. Each working is allowed to only have a max of 100 work items assigned to them. Each work item specifies the user that should work it (associated as an owner).

*For example:*

Jim works a total of 5 accounts each with multiple work items. In total jim has 50 items to work already assigned to him. I am allowed to assign only 50 more.

*My plight/goal:*

I am using a temp table and a select statement to get the # of items each owner has currently assigned to them and I calculate the available slots for new items and store the values in new column. I need to be able to select from the items table where the owner matches my list of owners and their available items(in the temp table), only retrieving the number of rows for each user equal to the number of available slots per user - query would return only 50 rows for jim even though there may be 200 matching the criteria while sam may get 0 rows because he has no available slots while there are 30 items for him to work in the items table.

I realize I may be approaching this problem wrong. I want to avoid using a cursor.

Edit: Adding some example code

```
SELECT
nUserID_Owner
,   CASE
        WHEN COUNT(c.nWorkID) >= 100 THEN 0
        ELSE 100 - COUNT(c.nWorkID)
    END
,COUNT(c.nWorkID)   
FROM tblAccounts cic
LEFT JOIN tblWorkItems c
ON c.sAccountNumber = cic.sAccountNumber
AND c.nUserID_WorkAssignedTo = cic.nUserID_Owner
AND c.nTeamID_WorkAssignedTo = cic.nTeamID_Owner
WHERE cic.nUserID_Collector IS NOT NULL
AND nUserID_CurrentOwner = 5288
AND c.bCompleted = 0
GROUP BY nUserID_Owner
```

This provides output vaulues of 5288, 50, 50 (in Jim's scenario)

Comment: Would JOIN or Subquery work for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Table structure? I bet you can get rid of the temp table, too, but we need to know about how your data starts out.

Comment: My data starts out with 3 primary tables, users, accounts and work items.

The pkey in the user table is the user id.  This is also a FK in another table that contains accounts.  The account table has an account number pkey which is a fk in the work item table.  The work item table has pkey that I'm using to represent a single work item that would take one slot.  It contains account number from the accounts table as a fk.

SELECT * FROM tblWorkItems --Yields all work items

SELECT * FROM tblUsers --Yields all users

SELECT * FROM tblAccounts --Yields all accounts

Comment: Method I use to get work already assigned:
Added code to my original post, looked horrible down here

Comment: I wanted to add another join to the above query to get up to X work items (50 in Jim's scenario).  The number of rows needs to be directly dependent on the calculated value 100 - Count(WorkId).

Answer (score 1):

It took longer than I wanted it to but I found a solution.

I did use a sub-query as suggested above to produce the work items with a unique row count by user.

I used PARTITION BY to produce a unique row count for each worker and included in my HAVING clause that the row number must be < the count of available slots. I'd post the code but it's beyond the char limit and I'd also have a lot of things to change to anon the system properly.

Originally I was approaching the problem incorrectly focusing on limiting the results rather than thinking about creating the necessary data to relate the result sets.